# Installing ESXI - Fatal error 10

Tags: memory, esxi

I'm currently installing ESXI on a brand new Server (I literally just took it out of the packaging). It errors out with the message "Fatal error: 10 (out of resources)" while loading /s.v00.

I read about switching around some memory settings but the only settings I could find were TOLUD, I switched that around (Tried 2gb, 3gb, 3.5gb) but it didn't change anything.

My server: Thomas Krenn RI1102H
[(Datasheet)](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/products/rack-server/technical-datasheet/frame.only_content/key.12385.html)

Tried ESXI 5.5 installer as well as the 6.0u2 installer, they both failed at the same spot.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'd start by focusing on the chipset support and video card (and vram). VMWare does not show your server, its motherboard, or the chipset version on their HCL, but I'm seeing some reports of successful installs with Intel C222 boards, so thats promising. Look at your bios vid ram settings for the integrated graphics and see if you can get any traction there. obiviously you have enabled the virtualization extensions in the bois, right?

Comment: I fixed it by fiddling with the ESXI boot loader, it's installed now. Sadly, I can't really recreate what I did exactly, it was long, painful, full of uncertainty. At the point where it started working I just stopped touching it.